What is the total mass-energy of baryonic matter?
From what I understand, conservation of energy does not apply to the total energy of the Universe, because it constantly expands and the new, created space has a constant non-zero energy of its own. However, a conservation of energy still applies to the total energy of baryonic matter, as far as I understand, so what is this total, constant mass-energy of baryonic matter?

This wikipedia article gives an informed answer:
Mass of ordinary matter
The mass of the observable universe is often quoted as 10$^{53}$ kg. In this context, mass refers to ordinary (baryonic) matter and includes the interstellar medium (ISM) and the intergalactic medium (IGM). However, it excludes dark matter and dark energy. This quoted value for the mass of ordinary matter in the universe can be estimated based on critical density. The calculations are for the observable universe only as the volume of the whole is unknown and may be infinite.
